# Stacks project for Galois representations and automorphic forms

Tags: reference-request, automorphic-forms, galois-representations

Is there anything like Stacks project for Galois representations and automorphic forms? I am not asking people to start something like Stacks project, just asking if something like Stacks project already exists.

The important features on Stacks project for this question are:

- it contains (among other things) full statements and complete proofs of the basic lemmata about the objects of interest, usually without redundant hypotheses. You can take what it says at the face value and not worry too much.
- it uses Git version control system which simplifies introducing corrections and keeping track of them (this is much harder to do with e.g. published articles). This improves its credibility in my eyes.
- it also contains a number of pedagogical examples which are usually difficult to come up with on your own.

I as a person trying to study some papers in the field would find such a resource useful.

P.S. As a historical curiosity, in the chapter on the trace formula in Stacks project there is a small amount of material on automorphic forms.

Comment: a similar question about homotopy theory: https://mathoverflow.net/q/322891

Comment: I think there are essentially no substantial mathematical resources in any field satisfying even the first two conditions other than the Stacks project and Kerodon.

Comment: To add to @WillSawin's comment, my first thought is that this would be very hard to do in automorphic forms, as many of the foundational results are extremely difficult (e.g., Langlands theory of Eisenstein series, various issues with the trace formula, ...) without seriously limiting the scope.  Though there have been some collaborative efforts at writing things down like the Paris book project.

Comment: https://automorphic.jh.edu The automorphic project started by Yiannis Sakellaridis